# Communication between multiple servers over internet with one static ip

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ldap, vpn

How to establish bi-directional communication (ssh, http, smtp) between multiple Ubuntu servers over internet where one server has static IP. Can LDAP help me here or only VPN. or a mix?

can i have nodes behind NAT/routers/firewall communicate with each other if they all join a LDAP network from the master server(with static ip and a FQDN pointing to it) or VPN is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script for the dynamic IP servers to check if their global IP addresses changed since last check. If there is a change, ssh to the static server and update the `/etc/hosts` file with the new IP (and record this IP locally to use in the next check). This script can be scheduled by cron, for example, every 10 minutes.

Comment: I am not much aware of networking. How this will help me? and the lesser servers will be behind NAT.

Comment: This will only work if you are able to connect to the lesser servers from the static one using their IP addresses.

Comment: that is where the problem is. they will be behind routers/NAT. basically once they are deployed they can be offline, in a offline intranet. behind firewall. depending upon how my client wish to configure his/her network. All i need from them is i want to take backups from them and if they fail i want my server to serve the application (web)

Comment: It sounds like you do not need bidirectional communication. Clients can ssh to the server and push backup data.

Comment: but what if server want to push code updates... long polling can work there. but i have one more hurdle. there can be an intermediate layer of servers. although that decision is upon me. whats the best scenario. once this setup is deployed. there will be around 500+ nodes

Comment: base your design on pushing/pulling from clients. just like package managers, you can poll the server for updates and copy updated code from the server. because if you have multiple clients creating tunnels will not scale well.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider that. But still please tell me. can i have such nodes (behind NAT/routers/firewalls) communicate with each other if they all join a LDAP network from the master server or VPN is required?

Comment: Its been a year. But i ended up realizing this. Is it really long to accept this as correct answer?